# Javascript calling prototype method from constructor with parameters

Tags: javascript, oop, methods, constructor

Im trying to call Person.showInfo() from inside Professor constructor, with its name and age as a parameters. Is it possible?. Please see the comment below thanks.

```
var Person = function(_name, _age) {
    this.name = _name;
    this.age = _age;
}

Person.prototype.showInfo = function() {
    console.log(this.name, this.age);
};

var Professor = function(_name, _age, _course) {
    Person.call(this, _name, _age);
    this.course = _course;
};

Professor.prototype = Object.create(Person.prototype);
Professor.prototype.constructor = Professor;

Professor.prototype.showInfo = function() {
    // How to call Person.showInfo() here ???
    // Person.prototype.showInfo() ...showing the Professor's name and age
    console.log(this.course);
};
```

Comment: so there is no way to implement polymorphism?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Person.prototype.showInfo.call(this);
```

Simply call the function as it is, but change the context.

Comment: that's exactly what I'm talking about. thanks